# HTML5 <video> in WebView or VideoView

Tags: android, html, webview, html5-video, android-videoview

Is there some easy way to play a HTML5 < video > tag in a webview? Or just play it in another Activity with a only a VideoView? (doesn't matter which one of them)
The Web-page (HTML5-code) is auto-generated when 3rd-party uploads a video (It ends up in a "newsfeed" of sort) with a < video > tag. I'm trying to make the user able to click the image of the video and go to my video_activity which only holds a VideoView and play it.

Any idea how to make this happen? I've tried a lot of different things but nothing works.
Please help if you've got an idea! I'd be **very** grateful!
Thanks in advance! And please let me know if you would want to see some code!

Comment: from which service you want to play video?

Comment: @edwin first of all: Thank you SO much for answering! But I do not understand what you mean by "which service"? I'm kinda new to android and to be honest Im a little in over my head, but I really do my best to understand. Could you please define? Thanks!

Comment: i mean are concentrating on any particular service (eg : Youtube) or you want to play any video available in internet

Comment: The video is an .mp4 that lies on the website. so no service like youtube or such. The person helping will keep uploading videos on the site that will end up as a < video >-tag. I just need to figure out how to play them.

Answer (score 0):

You can either look on API demo codes for playing video

You can use android [Video View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html)

Since you are using video tag  i'm not sure about the compatibility issues

For better performance your device should support [hardware acceleration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html)

NB: Since you are using MP4 there may be issues of Codec support and all ,So you must have an eye over that also